# Cannot pass dictionary with arrays to request body in swift

Tags: swift, rest, nsdictionary, alamofire

I have a custom class called Beacon with a "toDictionary()" method which returns a key value pair of the Beacon class.

```
let detectedBeacon = Beacon(id: "QA",
                                strength: Float(234),
                                proximity: "far",
                                time: self.getISODateFormat(),
                                wasOffline: false,
                                osVersion: "ios 10",
                                batteryLevel: "12",
                                uuid: "adadaad",
                                majorId: 4,
                                minorId: 5,
                                section: "QA",
                                region: "temp")


let array = [detectedBeacon.toDictionary()]
```

I created an array with this dictionary item (at present a single entry in array).
 Now I have wrapped this array to a dictionary in order to pass this to an API body.

```
let locationParams : Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["locations" : array as AnyObject]
LocationApiManager.updateLastLocationOf(deviceId: deviceId, parameter: locationParams as [String : AnyObject]? ) {
        (response, errorMessage) in

    }
```

"updateLastLocation" method calls alamofire post request.

But the server receives this parameter as follows

```
    { 'locations[][section]': 'QA',
  'locations[][uuid]': 'adadaad',
  'locations[][region]': 'temp',
  'locations[][userId]': '0001',
  'locations[][minorId]': '5',
  'locations[][proximity]': 'far',
  'locations[][batteryLevel]': '12',
  'locations[][majorId]': '4',
  'locations[][beaconStrength]': '234',
  'locations[][time]': '2017-02-01 06:42:03 +0000',
  'locations[][osVersion]': 'ios 10',
  'locations[][beaconId]': 'QA',
  'locations[][wasOffline]': '0' }
```

Why is it so?

## Update

My toDictionary method

```
 func toDictionary() -> [String : AnyObject] {
    return (
        ["beaconId": self.beaconId as AnyObject,
         "beaconStrength": self.beaconStrength as AnyObject,
         "proximity": self.proximity as AnyObject,
         "time": NSDate() as AnyObject,
         "wasOffline": self.wasOffline as AnyObject,
         "osVersion": self.osVersion as AnyObject,
         "batteryLevel": self.batteryLevel as AnyObject,
         "uuid": self.uuid as AnyObject,
         "majorId": self.majorId as AnyObject,
         "minorId": self.minorId as AnyObject,
         "section": self.section as AnyObject,
         "region": self.region as AnyObject,
         "userId": "0001" as AnyObject]
    )
}
```

The update location method contains some what similar code like this:

```
class func postData(apiEndPoint: String,
                     parameters: [String: AnyObject]?,
                        headers: HTTPHeaders,
                     completion:
                        @escaping (_ responseFromBaseAPI : [String : AnyObject]?) ->()) -> Bool {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true


    Alamofire.request(apiEndPoint,
                            method: .post,
                        parameters: parameters,
                          encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody,
                           headers: headers).responseJSON { result in
            completion(result.result.value as? [String: AnyObject])
            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are creating an array here that contains the dictionary as only element:

```
let array = [detectedBeacon.toDictionary()]
```

<s>Don't you want to pass the dictionary directly under the `location` key?
You can try just passing `detectedBeacon.toDictionary()` instead of `[detectedBeacon.toDictionary()]`.</s>

Actually I meant that `LocationApiManager.updateLastLocationOf` might expect a different structure. How is this method implemented? What parameter does it expect?

**Update:**

Well, what do you actually expect on the server? You are not sending JSON but just a dictionary's String representation right?